# How to create a vector from sub-elements of another vector in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a code like:

```
struct cart_point_2d{
double x; double y;
}

struct curve_point_2d{
double arc;
double kappa;
cart_point_2d;
}

std::vector<curve_point_2d> trajectory;
```

After `trajectory` is initialized I need to create another local vector that has the same length as of `trajectory` but should only contain `cart_point_2d` from each elements of the vector. How can I create `std::vector<cart_point_2d>`? I would like to know if there is any way apart from the obvious for loop.

Comment: `curve_point_2d` has a syntax error. You probably want `std::transform`

Comment: Nothing wrong with the obvious for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) can be used too:

```cpp
std:vector<cart_point_2d> result;

std::for_each(trajectory.begin(), trajectory.end(), 
    [&result](const auto& item) { result.push_back(item.point); });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) from algorithm.
For example:

```
struct Point {
    double x;
    double y;
};

struct Object {
    double val1;
    double val2;
    Point point;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Object> objects = {{0.0, 0.1, {1.0, 1.1}},
                                   {0.0, 0.2, {1.0, 1.2}},
                                   {0.0, 0.3, {1.0, 1.3}}};

    std::vector<Point> points;

    std::transform(objects.begin(), objects.end(), std::back_inserter(points),
                   [](const auto& object) {return object.point;});

    for (const auto& p : points) {
       std::cout << p.x << ':' << p.y << std::endl;
    }
}
```